# Confusion related to derivation of expectation

Tags: normal-distribution, missing-data, conditional-probability, expected-value

I was reading this paper related to sparse inverse covariance estimation of a gaussian distribution http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.5463v3.pdf.

The paper says that lets say I have some variables $x_1 ... x_N$ following multivariate gaussian distribution. Suppose some of the variables are not observed but some are observed then

$E(x_{ij}x_{ij'} | x_{obs,i},\mu,K) = x_{ij}x_{ij'}$ if $x_{ij}x_{ij'}$ is observed

= $x_{ij}c_{j'}$ if $x_{ij}$ is observed and $x_{ij'}$ is mising

= $({K_{mis,mis}})^{-1}_{jj'} + c_jc_{j'}$

where

$c = \mu_{mis} - (K_{mis,mis})^{-1}K_{mis,obs}(x_{obs,i}-\mu_{obs,i})$

I didn't get how come $E(x_{ij}x_{ij'} | x_{obs,i},\mu,K) = ({K_{mis,mis}})^{-1}_{jj'} + c_jc_{j'}$ if both variables are missing.

Suggestions /clarifications?

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula, $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$ the result follows since $K^{-1} = \Sigma$. Thus $E(XY) = \text{Cov}(X,Y)+E(X)E(Y)$.

Comment: If that is the case why isn't it used  in the case $x_{ij}x_{ij'}$ are both observed to get $(K_{obj,obj})^{-1}_{jj'} + x_{ij}x_{ij'}$

Comment: @user34790: Because we are observing the data already. So naturally, $E(x_{ij}x_{ij'}) = x_{ij}x_{ij'}$.

Comment: @guest43434: In other words, $E(c) = c$ where $c$ is a constant.